# How can I do an async fetch of all the data from an entity with EF6.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using WebAPI and I tried to scaffold a controller. This is the method it came up with for a fetch by ID:

```
    // GET: api/ExamStatus/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(ExamStatus))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExamStatus(int id)
    {
        ExamStatus examStatus = await db.ExamStatus.FindAsync(id);
        if (examStatus == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(examStatus);
    }
```

What if I wanted to do an async select of all the data from the ExamStatus entity? Can someone explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [`.ToListAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) extension method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<ExamStatus>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExamStatuses()
{
    var result = await db.ExamStatus.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Obviously this will select ALL the rows in your database and serialize them into the response.

Comment: How would I modify the response type as I would need it to return a collection?

Comment: Isn't it returning a collection?

Comment: Yes but do I need to modify the [ResponseType(typeof(ExamStatus))] ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Simply use `[ResponseType(typeof(List<ExamStatus>))]`.